# Deaths per year per Pakistan province? (2010-present)

Tags: data-request, medical, demographics, asia

I've been trying to look for data on the number of community health worker deaths in Pakistan, *ideally those who were working with polio vaccinations*.

In particular, I'm trying to look for the number of deaths by year and by province in Pakistan, from around 2010 to right now. It's difficult to find data, but even if I can only find numbers on the number of deaths per year in the entire country, I'd be forever thankful!

Comment: this question was on meta but is good enough for here.

Comment: Have you tried directly contacting government sources in Pakistan and/or the World Health Organization (WHO).

Comment: @BarryCarter I've tried government sources in Pakistan, but haven't been able to find anything for that. Same for WHO. Those two were actually the first places I checked, but I couldn't find much. There is data on polio cases,  vaccines administered (although that is not specific), but nothing with respect to community health workers. I kind of posted here in hope that somebody might have a pointer somewhere, but at the same time, I'm not really expecting anything to come out of this :/